# How to correctly display playing card unicode characters in terminal?

Tags: c++, unicode, terminal, centos

I need to print the Unicode characters for the 52 playing cards to the terminal. But when I run the code I instead get an 'A' with odd accents for the suit, followed by the card number. Based on my own reading I think the limitation is the font the terminal is using. But I'm unsure how to fix that. 
The terminal has no problem showing the suits themselves.
For example, the program has no issue with these: ♥♠♦♣
But is unable to correctly display these: ,, etc

This is what gets printed out:

[image]

This is on a Cent OS 7 VM.

Comment: Hi Ian, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We don't have enough information to help you out. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55963564/edit) to include more details like your code, your expected output, and the actual output *posted as plain text*. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "\n";                    // string literal
    std::cout << "\xF0\x9F\x82\xA1\n";      // UTF-8 encoded octets
}
```

If you have the character in a string, you need to encode it yourself, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20utf-8.

Comment: Both methods in your example correctly outputs the glyphs to the terminal, thank you.