# Dynamically calculating unicode characters

Tags: c++, unicode

For a game, I need to handle playing cards. I want to take advantage of [Playing cards in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode) which basically comes down to `U+1F0XY` where `X` sets the color and `Y` sets the face of the card.

I now need to implement a function which returns a string containing a single Unicode character representing the card. What datatype instead the placeholder `unicode_char_t` do I need to use to do math with Unicode characters?

```
std::string cardToUnicodeChar(uint8_t face, uint8_t color)  {
  unicode_char_t unicodeCharacter = 0x1F000 + (color << 4) + face;
  return std::string(unicodeCharacter);
}
```

Comment: `std::string` is a *byte* string. UTF-8 is *byte*-encoded Unicode. Use the UTF-8 encoded characters instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you provide an example (maybe with a different type instead of std::string) for the code in my question to point me in the right direction?

Comment: [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home) is a library that provides comprehensive Unicode support.  Your particular platform may already also provide excellent Unicode support.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419605/how-to-convert-unicode-code-points-to-utf-8-in-c

Comment: @Eljay Could you provide an example implementation of my small function abvoe using ICU as an answer to get me started?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963564/how-to-correctly-display-playing-card-unicode-characters-in-terminal

Comment: "*What datatype instead the placeholder `unicode_char_t` do I need to use to do math with Unicode characters?*" - since your code is doing math on the actual codepoint values, and those values are greater than 16 bits, use a 32 bit type like `(u)int32_t`, `char32_t`, etc, and then you can [convert the calculated codepoint value to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419605/) for storage in your `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an isolated place where you intend to use computed unicode characters, you can base yourself on the following.

The bit-wise encoding of `1F0XY` in UTF-8 is:

```
11110000 10111111 100000XX 10XXYYYY
```

You can construct that as follows:

```
uint8_t buf[5];
buf[0] = 0xf0;
buf[1] = 0x9f;
buf[2] = 0x80 | (color & 12) >> 2;
buf[3] = 0x80 | (color & 3) << 4 | face & 15;
buf[4] = 0;
return std::string(buf);
```

Comment: technically, `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a `uint8_t[]` as input. Unless your compiler typedefs `uint8_t` as an alias for `char`, you need to use a type-cast. And you don't need the null-terminator at all, you can pass an explicit size to the constructor: `return std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 4);`  Note that C++20 will add `char8_t` and `std::u8string` for dealing with UTF-8 strings.